# !LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined" !! in install mahjahn package

Tags: packages

I want to use this package.

https://ctan.org/pkg/mahjong

First, I can't understand Installation part (Run make install ...) in README.

Then, I run `latex mahjong.ins` from command prompt and get mahjong.sty.

I write sample.tex like this.

```
\documentclass[uplatex]{jsarticle}

\usepackage{mahjong}

\begin{document}

Nothing

\end{document}
```

I put sample.tex, mahjong.sty, tiles(folder for images) in a folder and try to compile tex file. But compile didn't success. This is Second probrem.

Error massage says like this.

```
>uplatex.exe -no-guess-input-enc -kanji=utf8 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "sample".tex
This is e-upTeX, Version 3.1415926-p3.4-u1.11-110825-2.6 (utf8.uptex) (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./note.tex
pLaTeX2e <2011/05/07u00>+0 (based on LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> patch level 0)
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jsarticle.cls
Document Class: jsarticle 2013/05/14 okumura
) (./mahjong.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2019/10/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2011/06/27' is available.

(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3candidates.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stackengine/stackengine.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.67 \str_new:N
                \l__mahjong_file_path_str
! Undefined control sequence.
l.67 \str_new:N \l__mahjong_file_path_str


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
!
! Control sequence \__mahjong_typeset_hand:n undefined.
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.197 ..._variant:Nn \__mahjong_typeset_hand:n {x}

) (./note.aux) [1] (./note.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on note.dvi (1 page, 276 bytes).
SyncTeX written on note.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on note.log.
```

I give up here.Please help me.

Comment: you are using a latex from 2011 and a texlive from 2013! The mahjong package starts with `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2019/10/01]`. It won't work on your old system. Update your system if you want to use it.

Comment: I'm happy to receive your comment. I update my system and success to use the package! Thank you very much :)